# Publishing a bot to Microsoft Teams

Tags: azure, botframework, microsoft-teams

We would like to publish a bot internally to Microsoft Teams. It seems one way to do this is to enable sideloading external applications in Teams. We do not want to do this as it will allow users to load a bunch of other apps we don't want to expose.

My question is, if I publish my bot to the office store, can other tenants see the bot? I see web apps have the "AvailableToOtherTenants" property and was wondering if this is what prevents other tenants from using our bot.

My goal is to publish a simple QnA bot to members of my organization only.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

In this case you would need to [publish apps to the Microsoft Teams Tenant Apps Catalog](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/tenant-apps-catalog-teams), in order to distribute line-of-business applications only to your organization.

Comment: Thanks for the guidance. I tried to upload the zip generated from the bot management > build page in Azure but received an error which makes me think the bot needs an app manifest provided through Teams App Studio. Not sure if that is accurate.

Comment: Exactly, as you can read in the documentation you will need an Teams app package which consists of an app manifest. The easiest way to generate this is using [Teams App Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/get-started/get-started-app-studio), uploading the zip with your bot code won't work.

Comment: My other recommendation would be to only accept messages from specific tenants, in order to make sure that your bot can only be used within your own organisation. This can be done in code using the [Microsoft Bot Builder SDK Teams Extensions](https://github.com/OfficeDev/BotBuilder-MicrosoftTeams).

Comment: Thanks Mick. If a bot is associated with a Teams App, can you still be found in the directory and chatted with in a 1-1 type scenario?

Comment: Mick, other relevant info: My bot was created using QnA maker. It lives in Azure and is already connected to Teams channel.

Comment: @toledotown I am not 100% sure about this. As far as I know, everyone who knows your Bot ID can approach your bot in Teams. However using the BotBuilder Teams SDK you can easily add a middleware which blocks messags from non whitelisted tenants. This would be my approach if you want to be 100% secure.